# Progress Bar Freezes part way

Tags: c#, progress-bar

So in the snippet of below I very simply look in a specific folder and copy the images from the source to the destination.

The copy is VERY fast and it works great for the first bunch of folders (maybe 20 or so) which takes a few seconds.  But then the progress bar stops moving and I get a spinning mouse cursor.  I can look in the destination folder and it is still processing the folders.

When it's done I get the the "Process Complete" dialog box, the progress bar is 100% and everything ran fine.

Just want to make sure the end user doesn't think it's frozen.

```
private void readInvoices()
        {
            string InvoiceFile = txtInvoiceFile.Text;
            //read in the text file and get all the invoices to copy
            string[] Invoices = File.ReadAllLines(InvoiceFile);
            //set the max val of the progress bar
            progBar.Maximum = Invoices.Length;

            try
            {
                //for every invoice
                foreach (string invoice in Invoices)
                {

                    //Set the source and destination directories
                    string sourceInvFolder = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", txtSource.Text, invoice);
                    string destInvFolder = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", txtDest.Text, invoice);
                    DirectoryInfo SourceDI = new DirectoryInfo(sourceInvFolder);
                    DirectoryInfo DestDI = new DirectoryInfo(destInvFolder);

                    //we know we have it in the CSV but does the directory actually exist?
                    //if so then let's process
                    if (Directory.Exists(SourceDI.FullName) == true)
                    {
                        //let's copy of the files
                        CopyAll(SourceDI, DestDI);
                        RenameFolder(sourceInvFolder);
                    }
                    //inc the progress bar
                    progBar.Increment(1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process Complete");
                CleanUp();
            }


        }
```

Comment: My guess is that you're doing all of this work within the UI thread. That would certainly freeze things. We can't really tell at the moment though, as we can't tell how you're calling your method. In general, don't do heavy work within the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI freezes because it's running in a single thread. A workaround to fix the freezing part is putting this line of code inside your loop.

```
 Application.DoEvents();
```

This code checks if there are messages waiting to be processed, if there are, it processes them before proceeding to another loop. You can use a ProgressBar control to let the user see how much is processed already. If you don't want to stay with the single thread method, use a BackGroundWorker to prevent the form from appearing like it's frozen. This is multithreading, which means a separate thread is processing something while you do something else.

One thing to remember though, using the code above makes the whole looping process go slower since it has to do the checking for every loop, which means more work, in return, you get real-time progress report. The reason it looks frozen is that the loop hasn't finished yet, you'll have to let it finish first before you can do something else because it's running in a single thread.

Comment: Be aware that `DoEvents` can cause funny (funny for me, not you) side effects if you don't use it properly. For example, closing the form while the loop is still running won't stop your program. Not until the  program exits the loop anyway. You can try to find and prevent all these corner cases, but you'll spend about as much time doing that as learning asynchronous programming the proper way.

Comment: @Steven Liekens, I totally agree. DoEvents isn't the best solution for everything. But it does work for simpler problems. When it comes to huge amount of work, multithreading is the way to go :)

Comment: Because this process is so fast as it is... I don't mind accomplishing it with the .DoEvents.  Thank you!

Comment: @Matt Winer, that's the thing :) The process is so fast the waiting time doesn't bother me at all. This is why I use DoEvents most of the time even if I've done multithreading too :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want `Just want to make sure the end user doesn't think it's frozen.` you should use multihreading .  the More suitable class for this task is [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

From MSDN :

*The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution.*

try to follow the example provided by msdn and put the call `readInvoices()` of your method in `DoWork` event

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running on the UI thread (at least I assume so as you have a MessageBox in your catch block).

So, it will not necessarily process UI updates.

Have a look into doing the work using the TPL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx